# How to pass a callable to a class so that it can access instance attributes in Python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have this class:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, callable):
        self.name = "Hey!"
        self.callable = callable

    def call(self):
        self.callable()
```

And I want to pass into `callable` a function that can access `name`:

```
def function_a():
    print(f"{self.name}")
```

So that this

```
a = ClassA(function_a)
a.call()
```

Yields this:

```
Hey!
```

How should I go about this? Metaclassing? Class decoration? Or should I just overhaul my architecture so that I don't need to do such a thing?

**Edit with a more clear example**

The former example seems like I'm just trying to access that attribute, this is not the case. In a more sophisticated demo, consider this:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, selection):
        self.numbers = [randint(1, 100) for _ in range(10)]
        self.selection = selection

    def select(self):
        return self.selection(self.numbers)
```

And then suppose I want the caller to be able to provide 
different *strategies* for selecting those numbers, like

```
a = ClassA(selection_strategy)
a.select()
```

In that architecture, `selection_strategy` is a callable defined
outside of the class that needs to somehow have access to that
object attributes.

Aaaaand just as I was writing this, I realized that what I want
is actually really simple, I just have to make `selection_strategy`
accept the arguments I want from the class and call it within
`select`. I'm sorry, SO, I've been working for a few hours
and this totally slipped by me.

Thanks!

Comment: You want a function with no parameter named `self` to use a variable named `self`…?

Comment: this seems like a pretty bad idea in general,,, but i think you can actually do it (most internals are somewhat exposed in various ways)

Comment: @DavisHerring take this example with a grain of salt. The point is I want `function_a` to be passed into the instance and then access its atribute

Comment: This is frequently done with inheritance. `class ClassB(ClassA)` and implementing `def callable(self)`. If that fits your architecture, its a good change to make. If you have other reasons not to use inheritance, what you are doing can be reasonable. You are just use a function that takes the object as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callable can't officially be a method because methods must be defined on the class object itself. But does it really have to be a method? You could just define the callable as a regular function taking a single parameter that just happens to be an instance object's `self` reference. Namespace resolution is different - you can't use class level variables - but if that's not a problem, this will work:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, callable):
        self.name = "Hey!"
        self.callable = callable

    def call(self):
        self.callable(self)

def function_a(self):
    print(f"{self.name}")

a = ClassA(function_a)
a.call()
```

Comment: This is it. As I put in the edit, it was actually pretty simple but my brain just snapped into 'oh my God I need to access this dynamically' mode and missed the point. Thank you!

Comment: In what way is name lookup different?  You can’t use unqualified names in a method to refer to class members anyway.  (I also wouldn’t call it `self` in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this is of any real use, but you could use

```
    ...
    def call(self):
        self.callable(self)

def function_a(cls):
    print(f"{cls.name}")

a = ClassA(function_a)
a.call()
# Hey!
```

Answer (score 1):

this seems like a terrible idea but here you go

```
>>> def hello():
...     print 'hello: '+name
...
>>> hello()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in hello
NameError: global name 'name' is not defined
>>> exec hello.func_code in {'name':'bob'}
hello: bob
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not clear what the point of any of this is, it is hard to know what answer will work. However, other than the obvious idea of the "callable" taking an argument, the simplest thing is to define a callable class

```
Class callable(object):

def __init__(self, otherclass):
   self.name = otherclass.name

def _call__(self):
   print(self.name)
```

then instantiate this with

```
foo = callable(ClassAInstance)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to be able to use self, you must make it a method, like this:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Hey!"
        self.callable = self.function_a

    def call(self):
        self.callable()

    def function_a(self):
        print(f"{self.name}")
```

Or, you can pass the name as a parameter:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Hey!"
        self.callable = self.function_a

    def call(self):
        self.callable(self.name)

def function_a(name):
    print(f"{name}")

a = ClassA(function_a)
a.call()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm well aware of how the standard way of declaring classes and functions work, but what I'm asking is a little more specific